# Is there any more securely way to protect and store a password than Windows DPAPI do?

Tags: windows, security, store

Is there any more securely way to protect and store a password than Windows DPAPI do?

My program needs to store a secret (something like credentials) to do automatic logins on Windows, and this secret have to be shared with other users accounts because the program can be run on different accounts but sharing the credentials.

I need to protect this secret from tampering to avoid an attacker to inject his own credentials and take the control. If the attacker has phisical access I know that there is nothing we can do, but.... currently, what is the best way to store and protect this secret?

Comment: If you want to control security yourself, you can use your own implementations of functions. This is technically an example of symmetrical key cryptography, because users have a shared secret. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380255%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography#Symmetric-key_cryptography)

Comment: Thanks @Hiroto but for symmetrical cryptography I need a key to encrypt and decrypt data, and this key has to be stored in the computer (for example a file), and the question is, How can I protect this key and the file against a remote tampering? An attacker can tamper both of them (the key, and the file with the encrypted data). For example, we can encrypt the data with DPAPI,store it in a file and protect it with ACL. But I am not very sure if this scenario is the securest one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to secure something against tampering, you are probably better off with a multi-level approach. The drawback to this is that gaining access (even with all secrets) is an *astronomical* feat and will bump up your login time on this.

Keep in mind, however, that a system is only as secure as its weakest point; you can have a file in a hidden encrypted volume behind even more layers of custom encryption, but if you have the passwords on a post-it note by your desk at work, odds are that it wont be secure for long.

The same applies with security on windows. ACLs and encryption are only as strong as your administrators' accounts. For tips on security, try [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

As for the system itself, implementing public-key cryptography (asymmetric encryption) through keys or digital certificates somehow and giving every user their own individual keys/IDs is a much safer alternative with far fewer risks.
Windows has supported pubkey infrastructure since at least [windows server 2000](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277320.aspx); you can even use a smartcard logon if you have the hardware for it.

Consider the following:
1. An attacker obtains a private key (with protection on it) from a user. This can be broken @2048bit in an hour or two on average hardware. With this example, you need only remove the public key of the user and have them re-generate a new key.
2. An attacker obtains a user's digital certificate, then you have two options:

```
1) Remove their certificate from the Active Directory store, ACL or other certificate store.
2) Issue a revocation on the certificate, and forceably expire it. This assumes your are acting as the certificate authority.
```

In short, this answer states one thing: **If you are worried about password security that much, then you should not be using passwords. If you make your system take forever to break, then the alternative route is a botnet bruteforce of a password.**

Comment: Thank you very much @Hiroto. I am agree with you. My system is able to detect an attempt of tampering and accordingly lock this account, but even with this security system my intention is to harden this secret as much as possible to complicate the work of tamper .